# how to store current date

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

We take a field `msgdate` in my table `private_message`.  We define the datatype of `msgdate` as `datetime`.

When we insert data, the field `msgdate` stores `0000-00-00 00:00:00` not the current date.

```
$Query = "INSERT INTO private_message (id, sender, msgdate) VALUES ($_POST['id'],$_POST['to'], now()";
$Res = mysql_query($Query);
```

Comment: your parenthesis are not even balanced.

Comment: You need to add an other perenthesis at the end

Comment: choose the best answer and vote it up

Answer (score 0):

you sure this works ?

```
"INSERT INTO private_message (id, sender, msgdate) VALUES ($_POST['id'],$_POST['to'], now()"
```

or should it be :

```
INSERT INTO private_message (id, sender, msgdate) VALUES ($_POST['id'],$_POST['to'], now())"
```

Comment: due to parenthesis your query work but it not store current date

Comment: you need to check your datatype , as I have created a table with the same structure and ran the insert statement from a php file , it is inserting the datetime properly

Answer (score 0):

just a parenthesis has been missed

```
INSERT INTO private_message (id, sender, msgdate) VALUES ($_POST['id'],$_POST['to'], **OneOfTheseFunctions**)
```

replace **OneOfTheseFunctions** with on of these three statements:

There are three ways to retrieve the current datetime in SQL SERVER.

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, GETDATE(), {fn NOW()}
```

**CURRENT_TIMESTAMP**

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is a nondeterministic function. Views and expressions that reference this column cannot be indexed. CURRENT_TIMESTAMP can be used to print the current date and time every time that the report is produced.

**GETDATE()**

GETDATE is a nondeterministic function. Views and expressions that reference this column cannot be indexed. GETDATE can be used to print the current date and time every time that the report is produced.

**{fn Now()}**

The {fn Now()} is an ODBC canonical function which can be used in T-SQL since the OLE DB provider for SQL Server supports them. {fn Now()} can be used to print the current date and time every time that the report is produced.

If you run following script in Query Analyzer. I will give you same results. If you see execution plan there is no performance difference. It is same for all the three select statement.

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
GO
SELECT {fn NOW()}
GO
SELECT GETDATE()
GO
```

dont worry, all of them are equal in function and performance!

Comment: after adding parenthesis it not store currentdate and time in database

Comment: can we use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP at the time of insert statement